# Install Apache on Windows Server Web edition 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Is it possible and legal to install Apache on Windows Server Web edition 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible.
2. It's not illegal.

The limitation in the Web Server Edition of Windows Server 2008, is that you can only install the "Web Server" Server Role. You could still run apache if you wanted to, since it's not a windows enterprise server role, but a third party web server